# Angular routeProvider and encodeURIComponent

Tags: javascript, angularjs, route-provider

I just stumbled about a tricky situation: I use an angular ui-grid to display a list of client names. The Id column will be used as link to the detail view of the client. It contains an `<a>` tag with ng-href.

Some of the client names contain characters which are not allowed in URLs so that I added an angular filter to call encodeURI component. That works fine but when I click on the encoded link
a) the firefox browser shows the link without the encoding
b) the angular routeProvider does not recognize the URL and does it's default routing.

My cell template:

```
$scope.cellTemplate = function(url) {
var s = '<div class="{{' + isRowInactive() + ' ? \'ui-grid-cell-contents strikethru\' : \'ui-grid-cell-contents\'}}" ng-class="col.colIndex()">' +  '<span >';
if (url) 
   s += '<a ng-href="#/client/{{ row.entity.id | encodeURIComponent }}">';
s += '{{ grid.getCellValue(row, col) }}';
if (url)
   s += '</a>';
s += '</span></div>';
return s;
};
```

My Angular filter:

```
angular.module('rcoc.filters', [])
.filter('encodeURIComponent', function() {
   return window.encodeURIComponent;
});
```

My routeProvider definitions (extract):

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
when('/home', { templateUrl: 'partials/home.html', controller: 'HomeCtrl' }).
when('/client/:id', { templateUrl: 'partials/client-detail.html', controller: 'ClientDetailCtrl', title: 'client' }).
otherwise({ redirectTo: '/home' });
}]);
```

Angular always routes me to the home page if the client name contains invalid URL characters, e.g "Customer (AMS@ITM/H)". The firefox inspector shows, that the encoding did happen:

```
<a class=ng-binding ng-href="#/client/Customer%20(AMS%40ITM%2FH)" href="#/client/Customer%20(AMS%40ITM%2FH)">Customer (AMS@ITM/H)</a>
```

I don't understand why this happens.

Comment: angular redirecting to home page on invalid url hit because in routeProvider you have specified "otherwise" clause. If none of the speficied urls matches, routeProvider nagivate to default url, in your case it is /home.

Comment: Yes, of course, that is the intended function of the otherwise clause. What I don't understand is, why the $routeProvider uses the un-encoded URL, not the one in the href attribute.

Comment: I am pretty sure your browser is decoding it for you before it gets to angular. Have you thought about Base64 encoding it or something? Maybe double URL encode using a filter?